# Use a docker image for a whole server

Tags: docker, server, vps

I bought a VPS server for some of my projects.
I'm wondering if it would make sense to run a single docker image on this server and do all the server configuration, projects config, virtual hosts, etc... on the docker image.

My goal is to avoid having to redo all the configuration work if I change of server.

Is Docker suited for this ?
Should I instead build one docker image per project (but then I will have to have multiple Apache instances I guess)?
Will it really save time if I change of server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm wondering if it would make sense to run a single docker image on
>   this server and do all the server configuration, projects config,
>   virtual hosts, etc... on the docker image.

No, You should run multiple Docker Containers on VPS, and one service per container.

> My goal is to avoid having to redo all the configuration work if I
>   change of server.
>
> Is Docker suited for this ?

Yes, absolutely suite for this case. Dockerfile will store the configuration for the container. And you also use Docker Registry to help you ship your container to everywhere.

> Should I instead build one docker image per project (but then I will
>   have to have multiple Apache instances I guess)?

Yes, you should

> Will it really save time if I change of server ?

Sure. But you need to learn to apply Docker in the correct way.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction,
Obviously I need to improve my understanding of docker first :)